# Raster aggregation on PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgis, raster

I have several rasters on different tables separated by time.
Like, table 1 represents rasters from 2016-09-21, table 2 represents rasters from 2016-09-22, and so on.
I'd like to aggregate the information on those rasters for 1 week.

I could get the value from each band with ST_Value, use an avg function and then create a new raster with the agg information on it, but this would be a lot of work.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [`ST_MapAlgebra`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html) for your purposes. You'll want the variant I linked to there, as it can take n rasters as arguments. It also accepts a callback function, so you're not manually getting the values for each band.

Unfortunately for you, there is not a predefined callback function to do this. However, it is very possible to write your own. I recommend you take a look at [this blog post from George McKerron](http://blog.mackerron.com/2013/07/21/map-algebra-callbacks-postgis-2-1/) for a more useful example to work from.

If you'd like a more detailed example, I've [written about it](https://nronnei.github.io/blog/2017/03/random-map-algebra-callback-in-postgis/) on my blog.

Comment: Thank you for following [Promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and making it clear that it's your blog! I'm a bit unclear on your second sentence, though -- which link? Based on the post history, I'd assume [this](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html); could you add it back in to your answer? If it's still relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I don't have enough rep on SO to add more than two links, and I figured the tutorials would be more useful than the docs. If you can, would you do so? That was indeed the link I had.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice! I edited it back in for you. Also, you don't need to add things like "Updated" or "EDIT"; if people want to know, they can check the revision history (right now, it's the blue link over my profile picture that says "edited just now", but that link's text will change depending on what you're looking at it -- it might be "edited 8 minutes ago", for example, if it's been 8 minutes)

Comment: Thanks for the info!